# window.onload does not work when minified using Uglify

Tags: javascript, minify, uglifyjs

When not miniifying the scripts `window.onload` does work as expected.

But when I do minified my scripts using Uglify-js Folder it does not.

If I write the following and minify it :

```js
window.onload = function() { 
 // My code 
 console.log( "HELLO TO YOU" );
};
```

It does not work in the browser.

But I f I write the following:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   // My code
 console.log( "HELLO TO YOU" );
});
```

It works fine!

Even just the console.log() alone does not print any thing using `window.onload` when minified.

**Any ideas??**

Here is the output:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    let e = document.querySelector("#main-header")
      , t = e.offsetHeight
      , o = document.querySelector("#et-main-area")
      , n = document.querySelector("#wpadminbar");
    o.style.marginTop = t + "px",
    e.style.top = n ? n.offsetHeight + "px" : "0px"
}
,
jQuery(document).ready((function() {
    let e = document.querySelector("#main-header")
      , t = e.offsetHeight
      , o = document.querySelector("#et-main-area")
      , n = document.querySelector("#wpadminbar");
    o.style.marginTop = t + "px",
    e.style.top = n ? n.offsetHeight + "px" : "0px",
    console.log("HELLO")
}
```

Comment: "my scripts" — Plural? Is that the **only** script in your test case?

Comment: "minified my scripts" — What is the **output** of using Uglify-js? i.e. what code are you actually executing in the browser? Please read [ask]; in particular the part about providing a [mcve].

Comment: "does not work" isn't a [useful description of the problem](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). Use the developer tools in your browser. Are any errors reported on the Console? Does the `script` element appear in the Inspector? If you are loading an external script, does it appear in the Network tab and get a `200 OK` HTTP response and the expected response body?

Comment: @Quentin - No several files are being minified.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the output, don't try to squeeze it into a comment.

Comment: No errors in the dev tools are showing.

Comment: @Quentin 
No errors showing in the dev tool console.
If the scripts work without minification then the elements are present in the inspector!!.
Yes all scripts do load as expected no 404 just 200,

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function() {
...
}
,
jQuery(document).ready((function() {
...
```

You have a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) between the function expression and the call to `jQuery().ready()`.

This means the value assigned to the `onload` property will be the *return value of `ready()`* and **not** the function expression.

---

Assuming the comma is generated by Uglify-js, then this is a bug in Uglify-js and you should probably report it there.

---

Asides:

- `addEventListener` is preferred over `on*` properties (and won't be vulnerable to this bug)
- `DOMContentLoaded` is probably better suited to your needs than `load`
- The [`defer` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#defer) is probably better suited to your needs than any kind of event though.

Comment: Yes the comma is generated by Uglify-js, more presicely by Uglifyjs-folder which I think uses uglify-js it self.  Unfortunetly this is a WP site and there is no direct way to use the defer attribute beside more code or plugings. I just tested the addEventListener with DOMContentLoaded and it works fine. Also as said in the question, the  jQuery(document).ready(function() work fine also.  I will report it on the GIT repo of the package. Thanks!

Comment: After further testing, it only works with a single call of `window.onload`. So all the different calls have to be merged into one single block.

Comment: @MarcDG — "addEventListener is preferred over on* properties (and won't be vulnerable to this bug)" — You've just found one reason it is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I ended up reformating my code to have the different functionnalities as named functions on their respective files and called the functions form one single call of the `window.onload` or better `addEventlistener( DOMContentLoaded)`.

```js
window.onload = function() {

 function one();

 function two();

 // ....

}
```